# Trigger the UP key in command line?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, debian

Is there a way to trigger/fire the UP key in the command line?

Instead of me having to press UP key.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [**xvkbd**](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/xvkbd.1.html) installed, you an use its `-text` option to send any string to the focused window as:

```
xvkbd  -text "\[Up]"
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me.

If what you really want to do is to be able to access and execute a previous command in the history without pressing up-arrow, there are various ways to do that:

- `!!` will execute the previous command
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>`string` will allow you to search for previous commands
- `!string` searches for a command beginning with "string"
- `!?string` searches for a command containing with "string"

Answer (score 0):

You can bind <kbd>Up</kbd> to different key combination using [xmodmap](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/xmodmap.1.html).

The following works for me binding the key to <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> (right <kbd>Alt</kbd> on some keyboard layouts).

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 25 = w W Up Up Up'
```